# Does timewalking drop better, worse, or equal gear to heroics

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Assuming you are max level (110) I am wondering if it's better to run time-walking or heroic dungeons for gear. Which places drop better iLevel? At the time of this question the current expansion is Legion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a **time-walking dungeon** which consistency dropped items of 830 ilvl.
War forged upgraded items went to 845 ilvl.
*It's also worth mentioning that when we beat these dungeons some people got achievements for "heroic[whatever]". So Time-walking is the same difficulty as heroic.*

Then I ran a **heroic dungeon** which consistency dropped items of 825 ilvl.
War forged upgraded items went to 840 ilvl.

**Summary: Time Talking seems to have slightly better gear. In addition, you can get weekend time-walking quests outside Violet Hold's entrance that give good rewards. **

Comment: If you mean warforged or titanforged with autoupgraded it would be better to reword your answer slighly.

Answer (score 3):

The item levels have been mentioned already:

- heroic: 825
- time walking: 830
- both can drop warforged or titanforged items

However, it's worth mentioning that any non-armor items (necks, rings,...) from heroic legion instances are better than those from time walking instances due to their different stats. Legion rings (and others) with higher secondary stats are a lot more valuable than old style items with a main stat and a few secondary stats on them.
*A Legion ring (neck, ...) with your preferred stats should always be preferred over one from time walking instances* (unless the iLvl difference is really high).